# Terraform 0.12.31 ... Operator issues

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have two terraform projects, one in 1.x and one in 0.12.31. I recently wrote a piece of code to process a complex object of configurations into a map of objects to be used in a `for_each` resource to apply RBAC's:

```
lz_container_rbac_list = merge([
  for container, rbacs in var.platform_rbac.storage_account.landing_zone.container : {
    for rbac in rbacs :
      "${container}-${rbac.principal_id}" => {
        "container"    = container
        "role"         = rbac.role
        "principal_id" = rbac.principal_id
      }
  }
]...)
```

This code works in Terraform 1.x, but throws errors in 0.12.31. It seemingly is treating the output from the `merge` differently between the two versions, but I cannot figure out why, or how to get the same outcome in Terraform 0.12.x

Error output:

```
Error: Invalid expanding argument value

  on locals.tf line 21, in locals:
  21:   lz_container_rbac_list = merge([
  22:     for container, rbacs in var.platform_rbac.storage_account.landing_zone.container : {
  23:       for rbac in rbacs :
  24:       "${container}-${rbac.principal_id}" => {
  25:         "container"    = container
  26:         "role"         = rbac.role
  27:         "principal_id" = rbac.principal_id
  28:       }
  29:     }
  30:   ]...)

The expanding argument (indicated by ...) must be of a tuple, list, or set
type.
```

Any help would be appreciated

-- EDIT

The input (`var.platform_rbac.storage_account`) that is being looked at here is a `object`:

```
storage_account = object({
   landing_zone = object({
     rbac_permission = list(object({
       role         = string
       principal_id = string
     })),
     container = map(list(object({
       role         = string
       principal_id = string
     })))
   }),
<snip>
})
```

The expected output from the code would be a `map(object())`. Exmaple:

```
{
  "container1-asdjijw-a2123-asd-2e2" : {
    "container" : "container1",
    "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
    "principal_id" : "asdjijw-a2123-asd-2e2"
  },
  "container1-1234-5678-1234-9876" : {
    "container" : "container1",
    "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
    "principal_id" : "1234-5678-1234-9876"
  },
<etc>
}
```

-- EDIT

Sample input:

```
platform_rbac = {
  "storage_account" : {
    "landing_zone" : {
      "rbac_permission" : [<snip>],
      "container" : {
        "metadata" : [
          {
            "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
            "principal_id" : "1234567-1234567-12345678-12345678" # AD Group
          },
          {
            "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
            "principal_id" : "0987657-9876543-987654-98765" # AD Group
          }
        ],
        "container1" : [
          {
            "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
            "principal_id" : "1234567-1234567-12345678-12345678" # AD Group
          },
          {
            "role" : "Storage Blob Data Contributor",
            "principal_id" : "0987657-9876543-987654-98765" # AD Group
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `var.platform_rbac.storage_account`?

Comment: A map of objects. I'll add a bit more to the question

Comment: I mean, can you provide an actual example of `storage_account`? Not only it type? Your code is not-reproducible without actual value of `storage_account`.

Comment: I can't prove it with the information given, but I would guess that `rbac.principal_id` is a value that won't be known until the apply step, which makes the `merge` function produce an unknown value which presumably this older version of Terraform didn't handle correctly, due to a bug.

Comment: Bugs notwithstanding, it's typically better to keep map keys restricted only to values you've decided statically in the configuration, because otherwise Terraform has to treat the entire map as unknown during the planning phase. If you have known keys but unknown values then Terraform can predict which keys will be included, and thus give earlier/better feedback.

Comment: The values are all set prior. Not looked up as Terraform isn't responsible for the group / user creations. Added another update. Worth noting that as per my question this code, exactly as is, works in Terraform 1.0.8, but does not work in the Terraform 0.12.31. The issue is understanding why the ... operator isn't behaving the same and what alternatives I have given that I currently cant move from 0.12.31

Comment: Your `merge` syntax is not supported in such an old TF version. Please upgrade to something newer if possibel.

Comment: @Marcin - it isn't possible which is why I am asking this question. I am looking to understand how I get the same output given the limitation of 0.12.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this in two steps, rather than the one. Firstly the `for` loops into a list:

```
  lz_container_rbac_list_prestep = [
    for container, rbacs in var.platform_rbac.storage_account.landing_zone.container : {
      for rbac in rbacs :
      "${container}-${rbac.principal_id}" => {
        "container"    = container
        "role"         = rbac.role
        "principal_id" = rbac.principal_id
      }
    }
  ]
```

Secondly, I take that output and merge/flatten it

```
  lz_container_rbac_list = merge(flatten([local.lz_container_rbac_list_prestep])...)
```

This gave me the right / same output

Answer (score 1):

Your `merge` is perfectly fine, for newer version of TF. But the equivalent code in 0.12 is:

```
locals {
  lz_container_rbac_list = flatten([
      for container, rbacs in var.platform_rbac.storage_account.landing_zone.container: [
           for rbac in rbacs: { 
                     "${container}-${rbac.principal_id}" = merge(rbac, {"container" = container})
                }
     ]
  ])  
}
```

Comment: This outputs a type of `list(object)` rather than `map(object)` meaning it cannot be used (directly) in a for_each without further processing. Ended up getting it working in two steps which isn't ideal, but your answer helped!

Comment: @Doug Thanks. If my answer was helpful, an upvote would be appreciated.